# C# List Order by which row have max value then order by ascending

Tags: c#

So I have a `List<Tuple<string, integer>>`

```
A 10  
A 11  
B 12  
B 13
```

And I want the following as a result

```
B 12  
B 13  
A 10  
A 11
```

Basically I want to check which alphabet hold the highest value, in this case

B highest value is 13
A highest value is 11

That means B will have to run before A. But B hold 12 and 13, so it needs to be run in ascending order. So

```
B 12  
B 13
```

then

```
A 10  
A 11
```

Is this possible?

So I'll need something like

```
foreach row in list.OrderBy(//order condition)
{
    //do something
}
```

UPDATE: Item2 is unique so the chance of 2 alphabet have the same value is not possible.

Comment: In the event of ties (if they're possible), what should happen?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: Ties shouldn't be possible because these are unique. But if it does, then I don't care which one run first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think maybe this is what you're asking for:

```
list.GroupBy(x => x.Item1) // Group by Item1
    .OrderByDescending(group => group.Max(x => x.Item2)) // Order the groups by the
                                                         // Max of Item2 (descending)
    .Select(group => group.OrderBy(x => x.Item2)) // Order within the groups
                                                  // by Item2 (ascending)
    .SelectMany(x => x) // Flatten the groups back into a single list
```

You can make this slightly more concise by combining the last two steps:

```
list.GroupBy(x => x.Item1)  // group by Item1
    .OrderByDescending(group => group.Max(x => x.Item2)) // Order the groups by Max(Item2)
    .SelectMany(group => group.OrderBy(x => x.Item2)) // Order within groups and flatten
```

Comment: Thanks, any idea what if I have Tuple<string, string, integer> instead of Tuple<string, integer> and I want to group first 2 strings?

Comment: @warheat1990 In that case you could change the `GroupBy` to `.GroupBy(x => new { x.Item1, x.Item2 })` (and then of course all the places that used to say `Item2` would now say `Item3`)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you need something like the following:

```
List<Tuple<string, int>> list = //getting your values

var result = list.GroupBy(x => x.Item1)
                .Select(x => new 
                {
                    MaxValue = x.Max(y => y.Item2),
                    Items = x
                })
                .OrderByDescending(x => x.MaxValue)
                .SelectMany(x => x.Items.OrderBy(y => y.Item2))
                .ToList();
```

- Grouping elements by `Item1`
- Searching the maximum of each group and combining it into new instance
- Ordering by max value desc, to place group with highest value on first place
- Selecting result item, ordered by value ascending

`result` will contain required sequence